# Scanning for CPU cache operations in multicore systems with C++

Tags: c++, caching, memory, cpu, multicore

I'm searching for C++ code / functions that allow to monitor read / write operations on the CPU cache / caches for multicore CPUs in order to be able to detect performance bottle necks due to competition between multiple cores accessing the same memory locations.

Everything that comes even close is appreciated. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

---

Thank you for all the answers so far. After going through them I think I should get a little more specific about the solution of the actual problem.

1. The desired outcome is a software for Windows systems written in Visual C++.
2. The software should be able to work with all CPUs and not just those of specific manufacturers.
3. Tools are handy when it comes to double-checking results, but as long as there's no fully documented source code available I won't get much from it.

At this point it would be of great help to get some VC++ code snippets like, how do I even detect the kind of CPU, the kind of cache it has, and when it reads / writes data from / to which adresses in that cache.
It doesn't have to be uber complex, I'd just have to work in a simple way.

Comment: How about [Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#cachegrind)?

Comment: @us2012, wrong they do: the PMU (performance monitor unit) is here for this purpose.

Comment: @Ben Ah, didn't know about that. I'll delete my earlier comment.

Comment: if you really wanna go all out, Intel's architecture manuals lists all the MSR's that keep track of various CPU perf counters, including cache ops, IIRC it also includes examples of accessing them too.

Comment: You do know that *every* memory read/write (except a few SSE instructions) goes through the cache, right? There are no dedicated "write to cache" instructions, there are only "write to memory", which has the side effect of also updating the cache.

Comment: If you want a non-free shrink wrapped package then Intel do something called VTune which apparently does a whole bunch of monitoring of this sort. I think they do a Windows version. May even work on AMD chips if they've replicated the architecture well enough.

Answer (score 3):

The best/easiest tool I could find is `perf`, For example, the following command:

`perf stat -e LLC-load-misses,LLC-store-misses /bin/ls`

Will output the number of last level cache misses for running `ls`.

see `perf --help`

Other good tools are [vTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe), or `cachegrind` which was mentioned before.

For a programmatic approach you can also check the [PAPI API](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/).